# How do I ensure that a many to many relationship is always populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Assume I have 2 models: Device and Setting.  I need to track and control the settings for each device.  The number of devices and settings will grow over time.  Clearly a many to many situation so I was going to use the "has_many :through" approach with a 3rd column for the setting value in the device_settings table.

My challenge is that as new settings are added I want to ensure that all devices have all settings populated in the device_settings table (the Settings model has a default_value attribute that can be used to populte the device_settings.value attribute).  Once a setting is added to the table its easy to ensure that new devices or edited devices insert the new setting row.  But is there a clean way to retro fit existing devices?

At some point the system will update the device settings and I want to avoid complex logic to handle missing values during this process.  I think its better to enforce that the bridge table has all the rows in the first place.

I can, and have, written some ugly code (loops etc) to populate the device_settings table on the :after_save on the Setting model but I am looking for something cleaner.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this fit the bill?

```
SettingsController

  def create
   ...
    if @setting.save
      Device.all.each {|d| d.settings << @setting}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This will work as long as you've set up the default value for that 3rd column you mentioned as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550688/how-do-i-create-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-rails-activerecords-model

Comment: Yes this is close to what I have, though yours is written cleaner.  I also created a companion to handle delete and updates etc.  It just starts looking very redundant.  Any chance that someone has gem that might clean this up?  This seems to be a resonably common use case. 

If not this answer looks to be the best.