# Can i make Rails this code more elegant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :hr_id

  def initialize(attributes = {:name => "Missing Name",:email => "Missing Email",:hr_id => "Missing HR ID"})
      @name = attributes[:name]
      @email = attributes[:email]
      @hr_id = attributes[:hr_id]
  end

  def print_employee
    "Employee No: #{@hr_id} - #{@name} (#{@email})"
  end
end
```

And i use it like this:

```
def help
    employee = User.new
    employee.name = "Dude"
    employee.email  = "Dude@gmail.com"
    employee.hr_id = "129836561"
    @employee = employee.print_employee
end
```

My question is, how can i make the code in `help` shorter and more elegant?

I tried:

```
employee = User.new('dude','dude@gmail.com','129836561')
@employee = employee.print_employee
```

But i got errors.

Comment: am I dreaming or you're really overriding the initialize method of ActiveRecord?

Comment: create a builder to set default values etc, dont touch the core class

Comment: I am new to rails and this is part of the learning process, but i am initializing the class User, which i created. Unless i am missing something?

Comment: DO NOT monkey patch rails classes... Rails is not your app, nor your code, if you expect it to work, be kind with it

Comment: Can you elaborate? From my understanding, i created new model & controller named User, and the 'initialize' method referring to the class `User` that i created, not the core class. Unless as i said, i'm totally wrong - in which case i'll appreciate some explanadtion

Comment: http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html

Comment: but, really... for default values etc, use a builder, dont spoil your class with this

Comment: I think that overriding the initialize method is a bad idea here, if you want to give default values to your model, try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550688/how-do-i-create-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-rails-activerecords-model

Comment: @apneadiving Perhaps it may be helpful to explain to the original poster a little more than you originally did, because you come off as a little blunt, snarky, and mean.

Comment: @Cupcake I guess that's what my answer is all about

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't click on the link you posted.  If I had, I wouldn't have bothered writing my answer.  For future comments like that, can we please put something that summarizes the link?  A simple "use `after_initialize` as stated in this link" should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `after_initialize` and/or `after_find` callbacks.  See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)

```
after_initialize :set_default_values

private

def set_default_values
  self.name ||= 'Missing name'
end
```

**NOTE**

As apneadiving has mentioned, this is not the correct way to approach your problem but I think this is the best answer to your question *how to make the code more elegant*.  For best practice, search for service classes like apneadiving's answer and how to use them in your controller to set default values.

Comment: yeah thats what I told him in comments but... after_initialize is run for every stuff retrieved from db which not useful (and can lead to perf issues) + its not the role of the model to know its default value, this logic must be extracted

Comment: see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks#cite_note-performance-1

Comment: this is an error to proceed this way... easy for sure but not correct

Comment: @apneadiving why? The model is responsible for its data, I can't figure out a better place. In the controller? And then you implement an API, you copy-paste initialization values into the API controller?

Comment: @pduersteler builders are a common design pattern. Dive into the existing litterature. I'm just following best practices and recommend people not to use callbacks spoiling perfs and codebase

Comment: @pduersteler just think about it: isnt is absurd to execute code each time you build a new instance AND each time you get instances from db? It should be done only once in a builder. I did quote the after_initialize in my comments before this answer was posted, but its no decent solution

Comment: yep. i totally agree with you @apneadiving.  I've never needed to use `after_initialize` and `after_find`.  Although I think this is the best answer to his question which is how to make the code more elegant.  This is better than monkey patching the `initialize` method.

Comment: Sorry but elegant doesnt mean clean paint over rusted metal, which is what after_initialize does in my opinion, thats why I disnt submit this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
class UserBuilder

  attr_reader :params

  def initialize(params = {})
    @params = params
  end

  def build
    User.new(default_params.merge(params))
  end

  def default_params
    {
      :name => "Missing Name",
      :email => "Missing Email",
      :hr_id => "Missing HR ID"
    }
  end
end
```

Then:

```
UserBuilder.new.build
```

Or:

```
UserBuilder.new({:name => 'foo'}).build
```

Comment: hey, just a quick comment. you forgot to set a default value to params so calling `new` without any arguments will not raise any error.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a Google search for something like "ActiveRecord default values", and one of the things I found was this Ruby gem that's supposed to set this up for you, so it might be worth checking out: [default_value_for](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for).

Example usage from the docs:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_value_for :name, "(no name)"
  default_value_for :last_seen do
    Time.now
  end
end

u = User.new
u.name       # => "(no name)"
u.last_seen  # => Mon Sep 22 17:28:38 +0200 2008
```