# Conflicting View Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a show page where I need to both show the student's units and create a unit for them. However an error is being incurred when trying to do both.

In my controller

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @unit = @student.units.build
  @units = @student.units
end
```

In my view

```
<%= simple_form_for @unit, url: student_units_path(@student) %>
  # form...
<% end %>

<% @units.each do |unit| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= unit.course %></td>
    <td><%= unit.mailing_date.strftime('%m/%d/%y') %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The unit.course call works and any call that is only the first child of unit, however when I call a second method on unit I get this error:

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

despite knowing that the unit exists, hence the first call working

Comment: Is mailing_date nil in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is that `unit.mailing_date` is `nil`, for newly-built records.

One solution would be to [define a default value for `mailing_date`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550688/how-do-i-create-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-rails-activerecords-model), either at the database level or in your application. For example, you could do something like:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ....
  after_initialize :set_default_mailing_date

  private
  def set_default_mailing_date
    self.mailing_date ||= Date.today
  end
end
```

Or alternatively, you could leave the `mailing_date` as `nil` and handle this gracefully in the view:

```
<td><%= unit.mailing_date.try!(:strftime, '%m/%d/%y') %></td>
```

If you are using ruby version `2.3+`, then I would advise using the [built-in safe navigation operator](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/), rather than `ActiveSupport`'s `try!` method:

```
<td><%= unit.mailing_date&.strftime('%m/%d/%y') %></td>
```

Finally, if you went with the above choice to leave the `mailing_date` as `nil`, then perhaps you'd like to display some default value in its place - for example:

```
<td><%= unit.mailing_date&.strftime('%m/%d/%y') || 'Not set' %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I assume you don't want the new unit bound to the form being rendered which is what is causing the error.

You could do

```
@units = @student.units.reject(&:new_record?)
```

To remove the newly built unit from the collection