# Provide default value for Model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I generated a user model with the following fields `user_identifier` and `notification_time`:

```
rails g user user_identifier:string notification_time:string
```

Now I would like to set the `notification_time` to a default value that would be to `17:00`

What would be the best way to do this? writing a callback? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you want to have this default in the database perhaps even with protection against `null` values? Do you want existing records to be updated as well? Or don't you care about consistency on a database level and an update before save might be enough?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `before_save` callback with condition, for example:

```
before_save -> item { item. notification_time = "17:00" }, unless: :notification_time?
```

You can also use [`attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) in Rails 5:

```
attribute :notification_time, :string, default: "17:00"
```

You can also set a default value in your db, but it doesn't seem to be a flexible solution for this kind of routine, cause in case you wanted to change the value you would need to run a separate migration instead of just changing the value in your code.

Comment: Will `def notification_time=(value)` work if i do `User.create` (without any attributes)?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: my bad, I digressed from the initial issue

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [How do I create a default value for attributes in Rails activerecord's model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550688/how-do-i-create-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-rails-activerecords-model)

Basically you'll have to run a migration

```
add_column :users, :notification_time, :string, default: "17:00"
```

or, as you say, use a callback

```
before_save :default_values
  def default_values
    self.notification_time ||= "17:00"
  end
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
an add on question: should notification_time be set as "rails g model notification_time:time" or as a string?

Comment: Good question. Indeed, postgres can handle notification_time:time with the hh:mm format. Then you can perform queries like Model.where("notification_time > '10:00:00'")