# Ruby - Initializing a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization

I don't know how to initialize information in a model before it is saved.

For example. I have a model called Car, and it has the attributes wheel_size, color, etc...
I want to initialize these attributes depending on other factors for each new car.

This is how I'm doing it right now.

```
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :initial_information

    def initial_information
        self.color = value1
        self.wheel_size = value2
    end

end
```

Comment: Check this post on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after_initialize`

would be the best lifecycle hook

Comment: why is it the best lifecycle hook. What is a hook?

Comment: I guess since this was the selected answer, you figured out what a life cycle hook is?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this initialization as early as possible; ideally immediately after the information you depend on is set.  I'd recommend writing custom setter methods for the attributes these values depend on and initializing them there.

So, something like:

```
def value1=(new_value1)
  self["value1"] = new_value1
  self.color = new_value1
end
```

Alternatively, if these values can be directly calculated from the dependent variables, it's much better to simply use a normal method.

```
def color
  return self.value1
end
```

Comment: When do these values get set?

Comment: The first approach I gave will set `color` every time you change the value of `value1` via the setter.  So for example, after calling `model.value1 = "foo"`, the value of `model.color` would immediately be `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

by doing an `after_initialize :mymethod`
your method `mymethod` will be called after the initialize (which is the constructor in ruby's objects) :]