# How do I set attributes in an ActiveRecord Object only if it is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Sorry, I think I am a bit stupid today

```
class Mutant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :style

  before_create :setup_values


  private

  def setup_values 
    style = "hardcore" unless style
  end
end
```

I like to call this stuff in the console like

```
Mutant.create(:style => "rampage") # expected is Mutant.first.style == "rampage"
Mutant.create # expected is Mutant.last.style == "hardcore but this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First off, see this question: [What is the best way to set default values in activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord/5127684)
2. `style = "hardcore" unless style` will instantiate a new variable named 'style' rather than setting the existing property. Change it to reference *self* like so: `self.style = "hardcore" unless style`
3. Lastly write the assignment to self.style like so: `self.style ||= "hardcore"` which is a shortcut for what you've currently written.

I'd probably write it like this:

```
 class Mutant < ActiveRecord::Base   
   attr_accessible :style
   after_initialize :setup_values

   private
   def setup_values 
     self.style ||= "hardcore"
   end   
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

just found it in the api

```
def setup_values 
  write_attribute :style, "hardcore" if style.blank?  
end
```

tadaa and it works :)

Comment: You wanted to use self.style = ... Doing just style = X, Ruby interprets that as a local variable, not a method call to #style=.