# Setting ActiveRecord model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to override a initialize in a ActiveRecord model, I just saw one thing that I could not understand what was happening there. I wrote this initialize method:

```
def initialize params={}
    super params
    @data = Date.strptime(params[:data], '%d/%m/%Y') if not params[:data].nil?
    self.number = generate_contract_number(params[:unit]) if not params[:unit].nil?
    self
end
```

Given the generate_contract_number works and Date.strptime works as well. My question is: Why  when I do self.number= the number is set and when I do @number= the number is not set. But when I do just the same with @contract_date= it works, and the self.contract_date= is set automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't override ActiveRecord's `initialize`; use an `after_initialize` callback.

For more details, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord).

I don't see anything about `@contract_date`, so I'm not sure what you mean. Without the model definition it's tough to say more, we don't know what `@data` or `@contract_date` is, or what "working" means. Bear in mind that an ActiveRecord's DB attributes aren't simple `@`-style attributes.