# Why is overriding ActiveRecord::Base.initialize wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, overriding

In several places, I've seen claims that overriding ActiveRecord::Base.initialize is wrong because it might not always be called:

- [How can I set default values in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord)
- http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html

With never versions of ActiveRecord (3.0+), is this still true? If so, what specifically are the circumstances under which it is not called when one might expect that it would be?

Comment: It might be better to turn this question around: Why do you feel the need to override Base.initialize?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it won't be called, it's that there already *is* an `initialize`, in `ActiveRecord::Base`.

*Could* you call `super`? Probably, maybe, in general. Across Rails versions, including future ones? Reply hazy try again. Cannot predict now. Ask again later. Magic 8-Ball isn't convinced.

There's an initialize callback so you don't need to, and aren't tempted.