# Why is this create statement giving the error "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Having trouble with this seemingly simple task of importing a CSV file via a Rake task, and storing in multiple tables.

My rake task:

```
desc "Imports the COGCC CSV file into wikifrac database"
task :import_cogcc => :environment do

    require 'csv'

    CSV.foreach('public/partial.csv', :headers => true) do |row|

        # create records in independent tables

        # create the Company object
        this_company_name = row['name'].strip!
        this_operator_num = row['operator_num']

        if !(Companies.exists?(:company_name => this_company_name))
          Companies.create(:company_name => this_company_name, :operator_num => this_operator_num)
        end
        thecompany = Companies.find(:first, :conditions => ["this_company_name = ?", this_company_name])
        company_id = thecompany.id
```

...

My Companies model:

```
class Companies < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facilities, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :company_name, :operator_num

  def initialize(company_name, operator_num)
    @operator_num = operator_num  
    @company_name = company_name  
  end

end
```

But when I run rake import_partial, I get this error:

> rake aborted! ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
>   wfrails/app/models/companies.rb:5:in
>   `initialize'
>   wfrails/lib/tasks/import_partial.rake:47:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   wfrails/lib/tasks/import_partial.rake:26:in
>   `block in ' Tasks: TOP => import_cogcc

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? Have been going around and around with this; many similar examples in SO, but cannot quite solve my error....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804868/why-is-overriding-activerecordbase-initialize-wrong

Comment: Why are you overriding `initialize`?  [ActiveRecord provides several ways](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) to bulk initialize models with their attributes.  Why are you adding instance variable to your model?  Are those not meant to be stored in the database?  The AR `create` method can't use the new `initialize` you created.

Comment: Just get rid of your `initialize` method and all will work.

Comment: you might want to consider using a transaction and create! so that you do not get models being created when the rake task fails

Comment: Thanks guys; removing the initialize did it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are calling create with a hash in your rake task. The hash is counted as 1 object (the syntax you use has implicit curly braces around it, so you are really passing in `{:company_name => this_company_name, :operator_num => this_operator_num}`), whereas you have overridden the `initialize` method to take 2 arguments separately. Hence, it complaining it only find 1 parameter where it expects 2.

#### Easy way

Since you are using activerecord, I would do what BroiSatse says and just remove your initialize overridden method. This will allow the hash to work correctly, and will automatically set the attributes you send in.

#### Special case

If for some reason, you want to set those two variables as part of the initialization, I would make sure you call `super` so that the rest of the object is set correctly.

`ruby
def initialize(params={})
  super
  self.operator_num = params[:operator_num]
  self.company_name = params[:company_name]
end`

But I only do this if I need these attributes set before I run any of my callbacks.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response...quite informative!