# How to create validations for initialized variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a variable `value` that is initialized when I create a new object. However, this variable is not a column of my table. I just want to use it inside my model and have it available for some methods inside my class:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize (value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

So, when a create a new object `@value` will keep the `some text` temporarily, for example:

```
test = MyClass.new("some text")
```

There is a way to validates the variable `value` to accept only text?

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :value => /^\w+$/ # it doesn't work

  def initialize (value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

I have tried all the answer, but my Rspec is still passing:

My new class:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_value

  def check_value
    errors.add(:base,"value is wrong") and return false if !@value || !@value.match(/^\w+$/)
  end  

  def initialize (value)
    @value = value
  end

  def mymethod
    @value
  end
end
```

My Rspec (I was expecting it to fail, but it is still passing):

```
describe MyClass do
  it 'checking the value' do
    @test = MyClass.new('1111').mymethod
    @test.should == '1111'
  end
end
```

I would like to raise an validation error before assigning `1111` to the `@value`.

Comment: I think you got your answers, but here is a friendly warning: don't override `#initialize` in your models. Otherwise you'll miss the one defined in `AR::Base` (unless you override it carefully with `super` call).

Comment: [Avoid overriding ActiveRecord::Base#initialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord), add a after_initialize filter instead if you need to do something upon object instantiation.

Comment: Btw, if you define attribute accessor, e.g., `attr_accessor :foo`, in your model you can pass the value in the default constructor as any other attribute: `MyModel.new(:foo => 'bar')`.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers, but I couldn't achieve what I want.... I have edited my question.

Comment: \w includes 1. `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9\_]`

Comment: @Chowlett - really? how can I avoid all number?

Comment: Depends what you want to _accept_. `[A-Za-z]` might be a good start, or the POSIX class `[[:alpha:]]`. `\D` is explicitly "anything at all except a digit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails does the validations only if you call `valid?` or `save` on the model. So if you want it to accept only values for your value when calling those methods, do a custom validation:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :value_string

  #further code
```

Setup your value validation like that under the protected scope

```
protected

  def value_string
    self.errors[:base] << 'Please assign a string to value' unless @value.match(/^\w+$/)
  end
```

These validations won't be called without calling `valid?`or `save`, like I said before.
If you want value not to be assigned with another value than a word-like-value **at any time**, there's no other way than to prevent it on initialization:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
  attr_value = attributes.delete(:value) if attributes
  @value = attr_value if attr_value && attr_value.match(/^\w+$/)

  super
end
```

**EDIT**

I would not recommend raising an `ActiveRecord` validation error when assigning not accepted values on initialization. Try to raise your own custom error based on [`ArgumentError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ArgumentError.html)

Outside your class

```
YourError = Class.new(ArgumentError)
```

Inside your Class

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
  attr_value = attributes.delete(:value) if attributes
  if attr_value && attr_value.match(/^\w+$/)
    @value = attr_value
  elsif attr_value
    raise YourError.new('Value only accepts words')
  end

  super
end
```

and then test it like this

```
describe Myclass do
  it 'should raise an error if value is assigned with something else than a word' do
    lambda{ MyClass.new(:value => 1111)}.should raise_error(YourError)
  end
  it 'should assign the value for words' do
    MyClass.new(:value => 'word').value.should == 'word'
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to define `#initialize` in your models like that?

Comment: Not enough. `AR::initialize` accepts a hash of attributes that will instantly fail with your `value.match`. The easiest solution is to define attribute accessor and do `Model.new(:value => value)`. Then you don't need to override `#initialize`.

Comment: Ok, defining attr_accessor and assigning via rails assignment is surely prettier, but I think my latest edit should work. Just curious.

Comment: Thanks @Beat Richartz but it is still not working... I have edited my question...

Comment: @gabrielhilal I think raising a Active Record Validation Error when assigning a volatile attribute is a bit misleading. In this case, I would recommend raising a custom Error inheriting from ArgumentError. I edited my question.

Comment: @BeatRichartz looks better now. You can remove arguments from `super` call. And feels like you should do something (raise an exception?) if `value` doesn't match the pattern. Plus, I'd extract matching in a separate method so you an use it both in `initialize` and validation method.

Comment: @KL-7 Thanks for the feedback! I made an edit because the question changed to include raise a custom error based on ArgumentError if the assignment fails.

Comment: BeatRichartz and @KL-7 - many thanks for your help and all clarification. Problem solved...

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using the `validates_format_of`. It's a helper method that essentially calls `validates_each`. That method validates specific attribute. You can check its source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L15-47).

Since you're trying to validate on instance variable and not on an attribute, you have to write a custom validator.

Validate with this instead:

```
validate :check_value

def check_value
   unless @value && @value.match(/^\w+$/)
      errors.add(:base,"value is wrong") and return false
   end
end
```

I hope this is just a representative example of your code. Please tell me you don't use `@value` as variable name.

Comment: yep, it is just an example... I have edited my question, as I am still able to assign '1111', for example, for `@value`

Answer (score 1):

Watch out.  the other methods will blow up when @value is nil.

```
validate :check_value

def check_value
  errors.add(:base,"value is wrong") and return false if !@value || !@value.match(/^\w+$/)
end
```

Comment: +1 for nil check. use `&&` instead of `||` however. this way your `@value.match` expression will not get reached. the correct syntax would be `unless @value && @value.match(/^\w+$/)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating your own validator, like so:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :value_is_string

  protected

    def value_is_string
      unless @value.match(/^\w+$/)
        self.errors[:base] << 'Please put a string in value'
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Validations run before save, so if you want to raise error on assigment you can do this

```
  def initialize (value)
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid if !@value || !@value.match(/^\w+$/)
    @value = value
  end
```

But i don't think that it is a good way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `super` when initializing. Try this:

```rb
    # Trigger validation on initialization.
    def initialize(attributes = {})
      super
      valid?
    end
```