# In Ruby on Rails I need to define this field "estado " automatically like "Inactivo", when I create a new "motivo de consulta"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
# in the controller
def create
  @motivo_consulta = MotivoConsulta.new(params[:motivo_consulta])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @motivo_consulta.save
    format.html { redirect_to @motivo_consulta, notice: 'Motivo de consulta fue creado exitosamente.' }
    format.json { render json: @motivo_consulta, status: :created, location: @motivo_consulta }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @motivo_consulta.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
@motivo_consulta = MotivoConsulta.new(params[:motivo_consulta].merge({:estado => 'inactivo'}))
```

Answer (score 2):

First your should have to re factor your code. You can do something like this

```
respond_to :html, :json

def create
  @motivo_consulta = MotivoConsulta.new(params[:motivo_consulta].merge({:estado => 'inactivo'}))

  if @motivo_consulta.save
    respond_with(@motivo_consulta, notice: 'Motivo de consulta fue creado exitosamente.')
  else
    respond_with(@motivo_consulta.errors, status: unprocessable_entity)
  end
end
```

Hopefully it would answer your question

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to set a default value for the field "estado" in "MotivoConsulta" model, try setting that value in one migration.

```
rails g migration SetDefaultValueToEstadoInMotivoConsulta
```

And in this migration set the default value of the *estado* field, as below:

```
class SetDefaultValueToEstadoInMotivoConsulta < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :motivo_consulta do |t|
      t.string :estado, default: "Inactivo"
    end
  end
  def down
    change_table :motivo_de_mudanca do |t|
      t.string :estado
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you should proctect the attribute *estado* from mass-assignment in 
MotivoConsulta class:

```
class MotivoConsulta < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  attr_protected :estado
  #...
end
```

A different approach can be used by setting the default value in MotivoConsulta class, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-default-values-in-activerecord).

There is something else that you might be interested in it's called the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and there are many [*gems* available to help you with it](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html).

Answer (score 1):

i would highly recommed you to refactor your controller and put that if logic of response inside a custom responder. =p

About your question, there is a gem that could help you: [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)
This way u could work with your business logic inside your model, which is where it should be.