# What is the Proper Rails way to "prefill an attribute unless it was set"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have a lot places where the following pattern emerges. The case is that I need to prefill an attribute with "random" information, unless it is provided by a consumer of the Model.

```
class Server
  validates :fqdn, presence: true

  before_validation prefill_fqdn, if: :must_prefill_fqdn?

  private
  def must_prefill_fqdn?
    #what best to check against?
  end
  def prefill_fqdn
    self.fqdn = MyRandomNameGenerator.generate
  end
end
```

I am looking for what to check against:

- `nil?` is rather limited and excludes values like `""`. It checks if it is nil, not whether it was set by a consumer.
- `empty?` catches more, but still does not match the requirement of
  "unless provided by the consumer", what if a user provides `""`? It
  also renders the `validate presence: true` pretty much useless: it will
  never be invalid.
- `fqdn_changed?` seems to match best, but its name and parent class ([`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) suggests that this is not the proper test either. It is not `changed` but rather `provided`. Or is this merely semantic and is `changed?` the proper helper here?

So, what is the best test to see "if a consumer provided an attribute".
Providing can be either in `Server.new(fqdn: 'example.com')` (or
`create` or `build`. Or through one of the attribute-helpers, such as
`fqdn=` or `update_attribute(:fqdn, 'example.com')` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test whether the params are present like so: `params[:param_name].present?`

[The `present?` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) (inverse of `blank?`) tests for `empty?` but also returns false for whitespace so that `''`, `' '`, `nil`, `[]`, and `{}` are all false.

An improvement on this would be to use [the `presence` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence). Then you could do this directly in your controller method without the need for callbacks:

```
fqdn = params[:fqdn].presence || MyRandomNameGenerator.generate
```

Comment: Thanks. However, presence, like `blank?` or `empty?` don't really match the requirement "unless set by a consumer". If a consumer does `Server.new(fqdn: " ")` it should not prefill it, but, instead, return the validation error; in other words: `presence? == false` does not mean "it was not set by a user".

Comment: I see. Perhaps then the problem could be solved by changing the UI. How about giving users the choice between custom content or randomly generated content? That way you can treat all entered content as "set by the customer" and validate accordingly. It also has the added advantage of letting the user know what to expect.

Comment: Also, I just realised you're creating a API rather than a web interface here. In which case, why not just set a default value, then let the user update it? (see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127684/2463468)

Comment: Thanks. My question is answered perfectly with the link you just posted. And, indeed, this is a RESTfull JSON api.