# Ruby on Rails, create with through control

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the following situation, taking over an existing website, I have model User which has many devices like that:

```
has_many :devices, :through => :credits
```

When I create a device it creates a credit, but some of the attributes of the credits are null. I'd like to know if there's a way to control the creation of this credit and make sure nothing is null in the credit created for the database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommended:**
Use default values in your credits database table. You can use a database migration to do this.

```
class AddDefaultValuesToCredits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :credits, :value1, :boolean, default: false
    change_column :credits, :value2, :string, default: 'words'
    # change other columns
  end
end
```

If no explicit value is specified for `value1` or `value2`, they'll default to `false` and `'words'`, respectively.

**Alternative:** You can also set default values in your Credit model.

```
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_values, unless: persisted?

  # other model code

  def set_values
    if self.new_record?
       self.value1 = false if self.value.nil? # initial boolean value
       self.value2 ||= 'words' # initial string value
       # other values
    end
  end
```

Comment: `after_initialize` is considered hacky, because that code is going to be run upon initialization of every single `Credit` object "magically". I would recommend going with the database migration only.

Comment: Good to know Ryan. I figured I'd give a couple of options. I'll update my answer to reflect the recommendation of using a migration.

Comment: @RyanBigg What do you mean by "magically"? I've seen people recommend after_initialize to set default values because they will apply even if you just call `Class.new` unlike database defaults

Comment: @RyanBigg You may see some of this discussion in the answers of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/how-can-i-set-default-values-in-activerecord) question

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin highest voted answer is from 2011, and is therefore probably irrelevant for Rails today.

Comment: @RyanBigg I was last edited oct 2012 though. Anyway, I was just curious about what you meant with "magically".