# If params[:object].nil? :object = value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to make so that if someone make a post without a title the post will get a default title.

I have tried this so far

controller

```
def create
@post = Post.create(post_params)
  if @post.title.nil?
    @post.update(:title => 'Unnamed')
  else
    # DO NOTHING
  end
end
```

controller

```
def create
  if params[:title].nil?
    params[:title] == 'Unnamed'
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
  else
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
  end
end
```

But it dosen't work. Any ideas what im doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The empty input value may not be `nil`. Rather, it might be an empty string `""`. Use `params[:title].empty?`

Comment: This subject can be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/how-can-i-set-default-values-in-activerecord

Comment: i tried that but i got an error. "empty? is not defined"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I my opinion it is the models responsiblity to keep itself in a valid state. Furthermore it is the best solution according to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles if multiple controllers change of update the same model. Therefore I would do something like this in the `Post` model:

```
before_validation :set_default_title

private
def set_default_title
  self.title = title.presence || 'Unnamed'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are processing strong parameters and so it doesn't work to set default title to `params` after `permit` all attributes.

```
def post_params
  params[:post][:title] = "Unnamed" if params[:post][:title].blank?
  #params.require(:post).permit(:title, ...)
end

Post.create(post_params)
```

I also recommend to use `blank?`. Here are differences between `blank?`, `empty?` and `nil?`.

```
nil.nil? => true
"".nil? => false
"   ".nil? => false

nil.empty? => true
"".empty? => true
"   ".empty? => false

nil.blank? => true
"".blank? => true
"   ".blank? => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want a default value for the title to be displayed in the input field.
Maybe this solution can work

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.title = @post.title.presence || 'Unnamed' 

    if @post.save
      redirect_to # ...
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Or a before_validation filter in your model can do the job.