# Rails 4 after_initialize not getting called on find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

In a rails 4 (currently 4.0.10) application model I was having a problem with a method not defined for NilClass error in a view, and so I decided to try to solve by setting a sometime nil to an empty string in the model's after_initialize thusly:

```
def after_initialize
  ...
  self.biography ||= ""
end
```

because, according to the docs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html , "after_initialize callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder"
yet, it appears that after_initialize never gets called and so the error persists, as tested in the rails console:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Presenter.find(2)
 => #<Presenter id: 2, mediahub_id: 2, name: "Craig", asset_id: nil, biography: nil, status: "active", created_at: "2015-08-12 23:00:34", 
updated_at: "2015-08-12 23:00:34">
```

as you can see, biography is still nil after the find.  What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: As you figured out, the reason is stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/how-can-i-set-default-values-in-activerecord). Thanks for finding out the link.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I'd like you to get credit for your answer as it was essentially right but did you remove it?  Can you put it back so I can accept it?

Comment: its ok mate! :) No need to accept. You had a problem in understanding, and you got it, that's all.