# Update fails first time, succeeds second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We've got this object, @current_employer, that's acting a bit weird. Update fails the first time, succeeds the second.

```
(byebug) @current_employer.update(settings_params)
false
(byebug) @current_employer.update(settings_params)
true
```

Here's where we initialise it:

```
  @current_employer = Employer.find(decoded_auth_token[:employer_id])
```

It's just a standard "find".

Current workaround:

```
if @current_employer.update(settings_params) || @current_employer.update(settings_params)

...
```

Anyone seen this before?

**Update**

Tracked it down to this line in a "before_save" call

```
  # self.is_test = false if is_test.nil?
```

Seems like `is_test` is a reserved keyword?

Comment: What's the error you're seeing from the false update?

Comment: There was no error message! - solved now. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, good to see the update

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The full callback, with the fix commented inline:

```
def set_default_values
  self.has_accepted_terms = false if has_accepted_terms.nil?
  self.live = true if live.nil?
  self.account_name.downcase!
  self.display_name ||= account_name
  self.display_name ||= ""
  self.contact_first_name ||= ""
  self.contact_last_name ||= ""
  self.phone_number ||= ""
  self.is_test_account = false if is_test_account.nil?
  true # FIX. The proceeding line was returning 'false', which was giving us a 'false' return value for the before_save callback, preventing the save.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

If it's failing in one instance and succeeding almost immediately afterwards, the typical issue is that you're passing incorrect / conflicting attributes to the model.

I would speculate that the `settings_params` you're sending have a value which is preventing the save from occurring. You alluded to this with your update:

```
# self.is_test = false if is_test.nil?
```

The way to fix this is to cut out any of the potentially erroneous attributes from your params hash:

```
def settings_params
   params.require(:employer).permit(:totally, :safe, :attributes)
end
```

Your model *should* update consistently - regardless of what conditions are present. If it's failing, it means there'll be another problem within the model save flow.

--

Without seeing extra information, I'm unable to see what they may be

---

**Update**

A better way to set default values is as follows:

[How can I set default values in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328525/how-can-i-set-default-values-in-activerecord)

You may wish to use the [`attribute-defaults` gem](https://github.com/bsm/attribute-defaults):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_default :age, 18
  attr_default :last_seen do
    Time.now
  end
end
```